# How to create multiple table in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

How to create multiple table in once in Amazon Athena?

```
create external table tab1 (id int, nam string);
create external table tab2 (id int, nam string);
create external table tab3 (id int, nam string);
```

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon Athena query can only contain one SQL statement, otherwise you will receive an error:

> Only one sql statement is allowed.

You will need to execute each statement in a separate query.